# When Ant-Man fights Falcon, does he change size through his own choice?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

When Ant-Man fought Falcon, Ant-Man became big again several times during the fight. One such instance is when Falcon punches Ant-Man. What caused Ant-Man to become big? Is it something the suit does, or something deliberate from Ant-Man's choosing or something else?

Reference:

Comment: Ant-Man was such an unfortunate movie, I don't know even if I want to see it in MCU.

Comment: At 1:15 it looks like Falcon tries to stomp him and he stays small, but at 1:28 Falcon punches him and Ant-Man becomes big.

Comment: @apollo: boooo. It’s fun! Paul Rudd is charming!

Comment: Falcon also does some weird double punch/wing clap thing at 1:47 that causes Ant-Man to become big again.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Boo to you! I like Paul Rudd. I just didn't like the movie.

Comment: Here's a better question. **When Ant-Man was fighting the Falcon, was he disappointed they couldn't get a [bigger star](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-m6UKS1L0YQ/maxresdefault.jpg) to do a cameo?**

Comment: @VenomFangs: Since the movie doesn't seem to explicitly note whether it's intentional, what can I do to improve my answer for you?

Answer (score 6):

The punch you reference at 1:28, I'm pretty sure that Ant-Man was trying to do the "size change punch" like he did at 0:58, but Falcon anticipated him. At 1:47, there's something weird going on, but it looks to me that Falcon was trying to generate wind to blow the tiny Ant-Man, so Ant-Man grew again so as to use his increased mass / surface area to slow himself (really, shouldn't he have maintained conservation of velocity like he does on his punches, though?).

So yes, it looks like he's consciously choosing to change his size as a strategic measure.

Comment: Increasing surface area for 1:47 makes sense. I watched 0:58 several times and he shrinks then jumps up and punches, as he's still small after the punch. So 1:28 still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The one at 1;47 looks like the Falcon got lucky and hit him in such a way that it made the suit make him big again, perhaps a glancing blow on the wrist?

Comment: @Richard, I thought the same thing but going slow through 1:28 (pause play pause play...), it looks like he's starting to get big before the impact of the punch and the result is the punch landing on his chest. I'm not sure if being big has any advantage to taking the punch, as being small with the density seems like it might be better? But that leads me to the question about how he's blown away so easily if he really does have the density/mass... and how he can ride on the bee's back. I'm left with more questions instead of figuring out the answer :)

Comment: There's been some speculation as to whether they kept the original Ant-Man's "same density when shrunk" or The Atom's "manipulate size and mass" to allow for more tricks involving hitting someone c.f. this discussion at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93231/23243

Comment: @VenomFangs - Pfft. This whole '*let's go to the Avengers HQ to pick up the Macguffin*" sequence was tacked on at the last minute and lacks any coherence.