# Is Ant-Man referring to any specific incident?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war, ant-man

Within the Captain America: Civil War fight scene, Ant-Man uses his suit to grow to several times normal size.

Right before that, he says this:

> I've got something kinda big. But I can't hold it very long... I do it all the time. I mean once, in a Lab. And I passed out.

[Civil War Fight Scene](https://youtu.be/gSdCnIA5qjw?t=170)

Is he referring to a specific scene within the MCU? Failing that, is it an allusion to something that happened within the comics?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

He's referring to an unseen occasion during development of the Ant-Suit, in a Lab, during which time he grew very big, but couldn't hold it very long and passed out.

That's it.

You're overthinking it.

Comment: -1  Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @ThunderGuppy Yes - the line from the film *IS* the source since it doesn't appear anywhere else...

Comment: @ThunderGuppy: Captain America: Civil War [fight scene](https://youtu.be/gSdCnIA5qjw?t=170)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I didn't mean the source from the question, I meant the source from this answer.  Obviously in the context of that scene, the line is *just* exposition, but that doesn't preclude an outside reference.  An interview with the writers where this question came up would be cool.  Alternatively, any assurance that the answerer is well acquainted with the comics would add credibility.

Comment: @ThunderGuppy: I can't really cite the entire source material for Ant-Man over all the years in a Stack Exchange answer. It actually sounds like you want a comic author to answer instead of a SFF.SE user. I almost guarantee you that you won't find a quote from an authority on this topic, because it's an utterly minute detail.

Comment: It's kind of silly anyway. Apparently he's still superstrong while large which directly contradicts the Ant-Man movie

Comment: I vaguely recall something in the Ultimates comics about Giant-Man (Henry Pym) passing out the first few times he grew before he got the hang of it, so it MIGHT be a reference to that, but it's a bit speculative.

Comment: @starpilotsix I'd look for the source if I were you. That sounds like the answer the OP is looking for.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition given that the Ant-Man movie is completely internally inconsistent with respect to how inertia, density, and relative strength are treated at different sizes - Civil War is actually consistent with Ant-Man's inconsistency!

Comment: @Hydrargyrum I've always assumed that the suit creates a local bend in space time making his small region of space bigger on the inside.

Comment: in other words: it isn't something most of us can sit down and calculate...

Comment: I don't mean that the movie treats inertia, density and strength inconsistently from each other. I mean that it treats these things differently from scene to scene depending on what would be coolest at the time. Example: model train at normal size bounces harmlessly off shrunk Ant-Man (train and Ant-Man conserve inertia despite change in size). But when the train is enlarged it smashes through the wall (model train inertia not conserved). But when Ant-Man is shrunk, his weight concentrated on a tiny part of the train doesn't crush it. Fun movie, but no consistency in its fictional physics.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum: Thats why it is called "Marvel Universe" To just shut people down that start arguing about how this wouldn't work in our universe, and how it seems to be inconsistent from our universe' point of view.... Its not supposed to work here, thats why it is the Marvel Universe....

Comment: As I mentioned in my [answer to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141869/why-is-ant-man-so-strong-when-hes-huge/141871#141871), the Ant-Man movie simply applies "Rule of Cool" to any given scene and Pym Particles work by making Ant-Man into a superhero rather than following any form of consistent or believable physics.

Comment: Shame, I was hoping for a deleted scene/extra that I might have missed. or at least some (humorous?) reference for fans of the comics. In any case, this appears to be the answer.