# Why didn't Scott grow tired in Endgame when he was Giant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, ant-man

Whenever we see Scott grow big into Giant-Man he ends up growing tired and passing out or almost passing out. We see this in *Captain America: Civil War*, where he doesn't stay big for too long before getting knocked over, and in *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, where he ends up passing out and falling to the ocean floor. In *Civil War* he even references passing out the first time he tried it:

> **Scott Lang:** I do it all the time. I mean once... in a lab. Then I passed out.
>
> <sub>*Captain America: Civil War*</sub>

However, in *Avengers: Endgame* Scott grows to Giant-Man and is that size for quite a long time before the plan to use the van's quantum tunnel. He doesn't seem to waiver or grow tired and keeps fighting through.

How come he didn't grow tired this time as Giant-Man?

Comment: Wasn't that problem resolved in Ant-Man and the Wasp?

Comment: @Shreedhar I can't remember it being but maybe I missed something or I'm forgetting.

Comment: He did grow large in *AaTW* at least twice without consequences (once at the school when he went to steal the cup) and once when he was riding the truck. Once he did faint (at the harbor while saving the lab). I'm gonna try finding if anything exists on this

Comment: @Shreedhar The amount of time and the size certainly plays into it. Scott mentions he slept for 3 days straight after he went big in CW when talking in AatW.

Comment: He does stay at Giant Man for a fair while during the Civil War airport scene - he keeps several people at bay, then eventually the plan is taken to knock him out, only then he punches out to normal. Is there actually a significant difference in length of screen time for which he is Giant Man in Endgame? (can't exactly count right now)

Comment: @DariM I believe so but the Endgame fight scene isn’t exactly linear so it’s hard to compare to the linear fight we see in Civil War.

Comment: Hey Siri, define "Consistency".

Comment: That's his secret; he's *always* tired.

Comment: It could be explained as a simple matter of adrenaline: for the first time, he's facing a horde of aliens that want to wipe out humanity, and have both the means and willingness to horrifically murder him in an instant.

Comment: Same reason he doesn't lose his density and power/weight ratio in contrast to his shrinking.

Answer (score 6):

There is no official source to answer this question[citation needed], so I will do my best to answer it with canon from the movies:

We know of 4 occasions when Ant-Man becomes (Gi)Ant-Man:

1. In a lab. We don't see this instance on screen, but Scott says that he passed out.
2. In *Civil War*. We do see this one, but he isn't big for very long before Iron Man and War Machine hit him in the face. After that he goes normal size, and is tired.
3. In *Ant-Man and the Wasp* he becomes (Gi)Ant-Man a couple of times, and eventually passes out.
4. And finally, In *Avengers: Endgame* he becomes (Gi)Ant-Man in the Battle Of Earth, and doesn't appear to suffer any drawbacks.

So we can conclude the In-Universe reason is probably that he got used to it, and the Out-of-Universe answer is that the passing out bit is just so he isn't so hugely OP, and in *Endgame* they just weren't so concerned about that, because the opposition was much stronger.

Have a read of the comments on the accepted answer on this related question: [Is Ant-Man referring to any specific incident?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162339/is-ant-man-referring-to-any-specific-incident)
This, for example:

> I vaguely recall something in the Ultimates comics about Giant-Man
> (Henry Pym) passing out the first few times he grew before he got the
> hang of it, so it MIGHT be a reference to that, but it's a bit
> speculative. – starpilotsix Jun 26 '17 at 17:29

I known it isn't official, but it's also worth reading what's on the [fandom wiki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ant-Man):

> Lang cannot maintain himself giant for extended periods time, as it
> causes some heavy stress on his body and if done long enough he can
> even faint. However, Lang seemed to be getting used to it the more
> times he does it, and instead of fainting he only gets very exhausted;
> by the time of Battle of Earth, Lang remained most of the conflict in
> giant form without fainting, exhausting, or showing any major
> drawback.

Comment: When the battle is for life as you know it, you say damn the consequences and fight. If you win and have to take a week long nap I think everyone would understand.

Comment: OP = overpowered?